# How to save multiple movie clip into an image air for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am creating a dress-up game, where the dynamic movie clip can also be saved as an image. Unfortunately, I was only able to save the image of one movie clip. Can anyone please help. I am new to flash.

Here is my code:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_18(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    GirlDone_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_18);
    GirlDone_btn.visible = false;
    var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(480, 386.15, false);
    jpgSource.draw(GirlBg_mc); 
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100); 
    var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

    var file = new FileReference();

    file.save(imgByteData, ".jpg");

    if( CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData ) {
        new CameraRoll().addBitmapData(jpgSource);
        GirlDone_btn.visible = true;
        GirlDone_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_18);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `GirlBg_mc` that you are drawing? What is the desired behaviour and what do you actually get?

Comment: The GirlBg_mc is the background of the game that i'm making. Then, I have some movie clip that is in front of that background but I don't know where to put it in the codes for it to be visible in the save imaged too. The question is how can I insert those other movies clips? I don't where and I don't know how.

Comment: Put all your drawable MClips inside one container Sprite or MovieClip, then draw that container itself...

Comment: But the movie clips are dynamic I'm having trouble in putting all those movie inside because I will get lots of errors that I know how to solve for example TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.at LittleMe_Keme__fla::GirlShirtWindow_349/onGirlShirtsClick()[LittleMe_Keme__fla.GirlShirtWindow_349::frame1:7]

Comment: Then, if I try to merged it into 1 movie clip there will be an error if I try to change the characters clothes.

Comment: you can also draw a part of your root `MovieClip` or `stage` that contains the picture

Comment: How do I do that?